# Problems with graphicx and htlatex

Tags: graphics, compiling, htlatex

I try to convert the file 3AHET.tex to HTML but get the Error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `test' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.244 ...        \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{test}
```

when executing the command

```
htlatex 3AHET.tex
```

I am using the graphicx package to display images:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
```

In the document:

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{test}
```

I had no problem compiling the document / converting it to pdf with MiKTeX & pdfLatex.

Comment: Welcome... Did you tried to add the extension (jpg or png etc) in the command `\includegraphics`? (Just a question because I see it looks for the name of the file without any extension)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tex4ht` compiles document in the DVI mode, where the only graphics format supported out of the box is `eps`. If you want to use `jpg`, `png`, or `svg`, you need to declare list of extensions that should be looked up in the image inclusion. This can be done in a configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png,.jpg,.svg}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The configuration file can be requested using the `-c` option for `make4ht`:

```
make4ht -c config.cfg  3AHET.tex
```